# How to store CCSprite in NSUserDefault

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have a strange problem while working with CCSprite subclass Creature.

Lets,my object is  Creature* creature;

The class Creature declaration-

```
@interface Creature : CCSprite <NSCoding>{

    int creatureAge;
    NSString *creatureName;
}
```

Implementation

```
+(id)initializeCreatureWithType:(int)type
{

    Creature *creature = nil;




    creature = [[[super alloc] initWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ch%i_default.png",type]]autorelease]; 


    return creature;

}
```

The problem is when i store my Creature class object 'creature' in NSUserDefault using-

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:self.creatureName forKey:@"creatureName"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.creatureAge forKey:@"creatureAge"];
}
```

And the decode it with-

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {

        self.creatureName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"creatureName"];
        self.creatureAge= [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"creatureAge"];
}
```

Then save the creature object using-

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:creature];

[defaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"my_pet"];
```

And the load-

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSData *myEncodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"my_pet"];
 Creature* newcreature = (Creature *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject];
```

The problem is that when I load this i get the property value of previously stored creature, but the image that is assigned to previous creature perhaps does not copied. Because if i add the newcreature to any CCLayer it does not display any image, though it get the property value of previous creature.

What can I do now to get the newcreature with image? is it needed to add image name as a separate property???

Comment: Ok,most probably the answer is- need to encode/decode everything that belongs to a particular class. So if i want corresponding image with object,then need to encode/decode this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply store the type as well and then do it like this:

```
@interface Creature : CCSprite {
    int creatureType;
    int creatureAge;
    NSString *creatureName;
}

+ (id)creatureWithType:(int)type;
- (id)initWithCreatureType:(int)type;
@end

@implementation Creature

+ (id)creatureWithType:(int)type
{
    return [[[[self class] alloc] initWithCreatureType:type] autorelease];
}

- (id)initWithCreatureType:(int)type
{
    self = [super initWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ch%i_default.png", type]];
    if (!self) return nil;

    creatureType = type;

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    int type = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"creatureType"];
    self = [self initWithCreatureType:type];
    if (!self) return nil;

    self.creatureName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"creatureName"];
    self.creatureAge= [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"creatureAge"];

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeInt:creatureType forKey:@"creatureType"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.creatureName forKey:@"creatureName"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.creatureAge forKey:@"creatureAge"];
}
@end
```

You might want to expose `creatureType` via a property as well. Note that instead of `initializeCreatureWithType:` it's "more Cocoa" to use the name `creatureWithType:`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that , but type is not enough since it be ch%i_default, ch%i_sad, ch%i_happy etc may be needed, so need NSString. However,that's not the  main problem, i had confusion that whether or not i need to encode image as a seperate property. Infact, at first i thought image will be  wrapped inside object itself, so no need to add it explicitely. Can anyone explain why not it does happen???

Comment: You can store the generated string (like `ch1_default.png`) in an instance variable and encode/decode it the same way I've shown with an int, then in in `initWithCoder:` you call `self = [self initWithFile:decodedString];`. If you want to store an image, use [UIImagePNGRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation) to convert an `UIImage` into an `NSData`, and `[UIImage imageWithData:]`.